# Sharepoint 2016 - Subsite creation - There is no memory

Tags: sharepoint-server, sub-site, farm-solution, site-definition, memory-leak

I have a problem with SharePoint 2016 that I am struggling with. I cannot find the reason why, but when I try to create a subsite, I always get the following error:

```
There is no memory on the server to run your program. Please contact your administrator with this problem
```

This is my development server and it is a single-server farm. I have 24GB of memory. However, I tried to upgrade to 32GB, but it didn't change anything.

This is what I get in the log files:

```
Event log message was: 'Échec de création de la bibliothèque « Documents ».'. Exception was: 'System.OutOfMemoryException: Mémoire serveur insuffisante.  Le serveur ne dispose pas de suffisamment de mémoire pour exécuter votre programme. Contactez votre administrateur pour ce problème.<nativehr>0x8007000e</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.CreateList(String bstrWebUrl, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, String bstrListUrl, String bstrFeatureId, Int32 lTemplateID, String bstrDocTemplateType, ListQuickLaunchOptions qlOpt, Boolean bProvisionViewsAndForms, ISPEnableModuleCallback pListInstanceModuleCallback, String bstrListInstanceSolutionInfo, String bstrListInstanceFeaturePath, String bstrListInstanceFeatureId, String bstrCustomSchemaXml, ISPEnableModuleCallback pListTemplateModuleCallback, String bstrListTemplateSolutionInfo)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CreateList(String bstrWebUrl, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, String bstrListUrl, String bstrFeatureId, Int32 lTemplateID, String bstrDocTemplateType, ListQuickLaunchOptions qlOpt, Boolean bProvisionViewsAndForms, ISPEnableModuleCallback pListInstanceModuleCallback, String bstrListInstanceSolutionInfo, String bstrListInstanceFeaturePath, String bstrListInstanceFeatureId, String bstrCustomSchemaXml, ISPEnableModuleCallback pListTemplateModuleCallback, String bstrListTemplateSolutionInfo)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.CreateList(String strTitle, String strDescription, String strListUrl, String strFeatureId, Int32 templateID, String strDocTemplateType, String strDataSource, String customSchemaXml, SPFeatureDefinition listInstanceFeatureDefintion, QuickLaunchOptions qlOpt, CreateFlags flags)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.Add(String title, String description, String url, String featureId, Int32 templateType, String docTemplateType, QuickLaunchOptions quickLaunchOptions)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.Add(String title, String description, String url, String featureId, Int32 templateType, String docTemplateType)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.ProvisioningHelper.AddList(SPListCollection lists, String urlName, String title, String description, Guid featureId, Guid[] previousVersionFeatureIds, Int32 templateType, Boolean& newListCreated)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.AreaProvisioner.CreateDocumentsDocumentLibrary(SPList approvalTaskList)'


Publishing Feature activation failed. Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Échec de la mise en service. Détails : Échec de création de la bibliothèque « Documents ». Exception d'origine : Mémoire serveur insuffisante.  Le serveur ne dispose pas de suffisamment de mémoire pour exécuter votre programme. Contactez votre administrateur pour ce problème.<nativehr>0x8007000e</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack> ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Mémoire serveur insuffisante.  Le serveur ne dispose pas de suffisamment de mémoire pour exécuter votre programme. Contactez votre administrateur pour ce problème.<nativehr>0x8007000e</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.CreateList(String bstrWebUrl, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, String bstrListUrl, String bstrFeatureId, Int32 lTemplateID, String bstrDocTemplateType, ListQuickLaunchOptions qlOpt, Boolean bProvisionViewsAndForms, ISPEnableModuleCallback pListInstanceModuleCallback, String bstrListInstanceSolutionInfo, String bstrListInstanceFeaturePath, String bstrListInstanceFeatureId, String bstrCustomSchemaXml, ISPEnableModuleCallback pListTemplateModuleCallback, String bstrListTemplateSolutionInfo)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CreateList(String bstrWebUrl, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, String bstrListUrl, String bstrFeatureId, Int32 lTemplateID, String bstrDocTemplateType, ListQuickLaunchOptions qlOpt, Boolean bProvisionViewsAndForms, ISPEnableModuleCallback pListInstanceModuleCallback, String bstrListInstanceSolutionInfo, String bstrListInstanceFeaturePath, String bstrListInstanceFeatureId, String bstrCustomSchemaXml, ISPEnableModuleCallback pListTemplateModuleCallback, String bstrListTemplateSolutionInfo)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.CreateList(String strTitle, String strDescription, String strListUrl, String strFeatureId, Int32 templateID, String strDocTemplateType, String strDataSource, String customSchemaXml, SPFeatureDefinition listInstanceFeatureDefintion, QuickLaunchOptions qlOpt, CreateFlags flags)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.Add(String title, String description, String url, String featureId, Int32 templateType, String docTemplateType, QuickLaunchOptions quickLaunchOptions)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.Add(String title, String description, String url, String featureId, Int32 templateType, String docTemplateType)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.ProvisioningHelper.AddList(SPListCollection lists, String urlName, String title, String description, Guid featureId, Guid[] previousVersionFeatureIds, Int32 templateType, Boolean& newListCreated)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.AreaProvisioner.CreateDocumentsDocumentLibrary(SPList approvalTaskList)     -
-- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.AreaProvisioner.CreateDocumentsDocumentLibrary(SPList approvalTaskList)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.AreaProvisioner.Provision()    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingFeatureHandler.<>c__DisplayClass3.<FeatureActivated>b__0()    
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.CultureUtility.RunWithCultureScope(CodeToRunWithCultureScope code)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingFeatureHandler.FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties receiverProperties).


Exception in EnsureFeaturesActivatedAtWeb: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Échec de la mise en service. Détails : Échec de création de la bibliothèque « Documents ». Exception d'origine : Mémoire serveur insuffisante.  Le serveur ne dispose pas de suffisamment de mémoire pour exécuter votre programme. Contactez votre administrateur pour ce problème.<nativehr>0x8007000e</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack> ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Mémoire serveur insuffisante.  Le serveur ne dispose pas de suffisamment de mémoire pour exécuter votre programme. Contactez votre administrateur pour ce problème.<nativehr>0x8007000e</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.CreateList(String bstrWebUrl, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, String bstrListUrl, String bstrFeatureId, Int32 lTemplateID, String bstrDocTemplateType, ListQuickLaunchOptions qlOpt, Boolean bProvisionViewsAndForms, ISPEnableModuleCallback pListInstanceModuleCallback, String bstrListInstanceSolutionInfo, String bstrListInstanceFeaturePath, String bstrListInstanceFeatureId, String bstrCustomSchemaXml, ISPEnableModuleCallback pListTemplateModuleCallback, String bstrListTemplateSolutionInfo)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CreateList(String bstrWebUrl, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, String bstrListUrl, String bstrFeatureId, Int32 lTemplateID, String bstrDocTemplateType, ListQuickLaunchOptions qlOpt, Boolean bProvisionViewsAndForms, ISPEnableModuleCallback pListInstanceModuleCallback, String bstrListInstanceSolutionInfo, String bstrListInstanceFeaturePath, String bstrListInstanceFeatureId, String bstrCustomSchemaXml, ISPEnableModuleCallback pListTemplateModuleCallback, String bstrListTemplateSolutionInfo)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.CreateList(String strTitle, String strDescription, String strListUrl, String strFeatureId, Int32 templateID, String strDocTemplateType, String strDataSource, String customSchemaXml, SPFeatureDefinition listInstanceFeatureDefintion, QuickLaunchOptions qlOpt, CreateFlags flags)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.Add(String title, String description, String url, String featureId, Int32 templateType, String docTemplateType, QuickLaunchOptions quickLaunchOptions)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.Add(String title, String description, String url, String featureId, Int32 templateType, String docTemplateType)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.ProvisioningHelper.AddList(SPListCollection lists, String urlName, String title, String description, Guid featureId, Guid[] previousVersionFeatureIds, Int32 templateType, Boolean& newListCreated)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.AreaProvisioner.CreateDocumentsDocumentLibrary(SPList approvalTaskList)     -
-- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.AreaProvisioner.CreateDocumentsDocumentLibrary(SPList approvalTaskList)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.AreaProvisioner.Provision()    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingFeatureHandler.<>c__DisplayClass3.<FeatureActivated>b__0()    
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.CultureUtility.RunWithCultureScope(CodeToRunWithCultureScope code)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingFeatureHandler.FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties receiverProperties)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.DoActivationCallout(Boolean fActivate, Boolean fForce)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternalWithName(Guid featureId, Int32 compatibilityLevel, String featureName, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly, Boolean fIgnoreMissing, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureManager.EnsureFeaturesActivatedCore(SPSite site, SPWeb web, String sFeatures, Boolean fMarkOnly, Boolean fIgnoreMissing)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureManager.<>c__DisplayClass7.<EnsureFeaturesActivatedAtWeb>b__6()


Leaked record detected with address 000002B68FBB9440, name xmlschemas(39)-15-1036-onet.xml, and thread local refcount 1.


AddRef stack 1 for record with address 000002B68FBB9440: owssvr.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000002FECC5)
at 0x00007FF8F7F4ECC5 owssvr.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000000180173)
at 0x00007FF8F7DD0173 owssvr.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=000000000018449B)
at 0x00007FF8F7DD449B owssvr.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000DF962)
at 0x00007FF8F7D2F962 owssvr.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000DFBBD)
at 0x00007FF8F7D2FBBD owssvr.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000DFAD2)
at 0x00007FF8F7D2FAD2 owssvr.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000DFC60)
at 0x00007FF8F7D2FC60 owssvr.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000FAF35)
at 0x00007FF8F7D4AF35 owssvr.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000FECE3)
at 0x00007FF8F7D4ECE3 owssvr.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000F3309)
at 0x00007FF8F7D43309 owssvr.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000000014378)
at 0x00007FF8F7C64378 Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000906D2)
at 0x00007FF8F83906D2
```

I have this problem whenever I choose to create a subsite with a native site definition our a custom site definition in every web application. At first, I thought it was the package I am working on that was the problem, but the error occurs even when the package is retracted and the debugging is stopped in Visual Studio (when I debug, I just hit F5, I don't attach manually to w3wp). My package is a Farm Solution and it just contains a Site scoped feature, a Master Page, an Application Page, an onet.xml file and two WEBTEMP*.xml file deployed in 1033 and 1036. I searched everywhere and did not find any trace of those files, so I assume they are completely and well retracted.

The account that I used to deploy the package and with I am connected is a site collection administrator, has full control in SharePoint and can access to the Central Administration. It is also referenced in SQL Server as a db owner.

I stopped services like SharePoint Search Services or other high consuming memory services, restarted the server, made several IISReset,
recycle Application Pools, stopped unused Application Pools, enable Blob Cache, deactivated and reactivated features, decreased the maximum allocated memory for SQL Server (20480 to 10240), but nothing worked. I even re-run the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard.

I checked everywhere I thought and checked the server with the system administrator and everything seems to be fine. I also checked in the Event Viewer and with Process Monitor, but I did not find anything special.

In the log files, a few lines above, I also found the following line:

```
Claims Windows Sign-In: Sending 401 for request '/_layouts/15/newsbweb.aspx' because the user is not authenticated and resource requires authentication.
```

...but I don't know if it is related.

At the end of the day, I think the memory issue is a false error. If I try to apply the developer site definition to the root collection, I get the following message:

```
Exception attempting to ApplyWebTemplate to SPWeb http://tenant.sharepoint.com: System.ArgumentException: File or arguments not valid for site template 'STS#0'.  Parameter name: WebTemplate    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebTemplateCollection.get_Item(String strKey)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ApplyWebTemplate(String strWebTemplate, Page page, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.AppDevelopment.DeveloperSiteProvisioningProvider.Provision(SPWebProvisioningProperties properties)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ProvisionWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate webTemplate, String webTemplateToUse, SPFeatureWebTemplate featureWebTemplate, Page page, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors)  at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ApplyWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate webTemplate, Page page, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.TemplatePickerUtil.ApplyWebTemplateAndRedirect(SPWeb Web, String strWebTemplate, Nullable`1 bSharedNav, Boolean bOnTopNav, Boolean bOnQuickLaunch, Page page, Boolean bDeleteOnError, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors) 

Application error when access /_layouts/15/templatepick.aspx, Error=File or arguments not valid for site template 'STS#0'.  Parameter name: WebTemplate  
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebTemplateCollection.get_Item(String strKey)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ApplyWebTemplate(String strWebTemplate, Page page, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.AppDevelopment.DeveloperSiteProvisioningProvider.Provision(SPWebProvisioningProperties properties)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ProvisionWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate webTemplate, String webTemplateToUse, SPFeatureWebTemplate featureWebTemplate, Page page, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ApplyWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate webTemplate, Page page, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.TemplatePickerUtil.ApplyWebTemplateAndRedirect(SPWeb Web, String strWebTemplate, Nullable`1 bSharedNav, Boolean bOnTopNav, Boolean bOnQuickLaunch, Page page, Boolean bDeleteOnError, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.TemplatePickPage.BtnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)    
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)    
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Now, if I run *Get-SPWebTemplate* or *Get-SPWebTemplate "STS*"*, I cannot find STS#0.

Does anyone have a suggestion? I have been searching for hours and it is driving me crazy!

Many thanks in advanced!

### SOLUTION (?)

After long, very long hours, I noticed that the WEBTEMP.XML was missing in 1033 and 1036. I don't know why! Anyway, I put back this file in place from another server. After various tests, I can create subsites again!